# Spring annotation @Autowired cannot be imported in IntelliJ using gradle

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, autowired

As the title says. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4

My gradle file is following:

```
group 'org.ks'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.7.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

But the attempt to use @Autowired annotation causes compilation error

```
package app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class AutowiredCls {

    @Autowired
    private int app_name;

}
```

Compiler marks import and @Autowired as errors (red underline)

application.yml:

```
app.name = autowired_sample
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below dependencies, you can refer to [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) for more details

```
dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't help :(


* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'autowired_sample'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web, build_2d49x9ndo4rbc0rejb3gqa171$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure5@19f252cc] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your project has any dependencies at all.  (I can see that your `buildscript` has dependencies... but these will not apply to the project sources thamselves.)

Here is a `build.gradle` file from a project I once generated using https://start.spring.io:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'war'


war {
    baseName = 'soffit-samples'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

The project itself (my sources) contains 2 dependencies defined for the `compile` scope:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web

Both of these are Spring dependencies.  I imagine that one (or both) of these give my sources access to the `@Autowired` annotation... either directly or transitively (probably transitively).

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I 've found the solution. It's best to visit start.spring.io to generate gradle.

build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
springVersion=1.5.8.RELEASE
```